# Command line options for windows executables

Tags: windows, executable, file-properties

In windows i used to be able to give executables command line options.
go to properties for that file or shortcut, and add the command to the end of the path for the file

example: `C:\3DO\Heroes3\HEROES3.EXE /nwcgrail` where "/nwcgrail" is the extra option the program will run with.

Now I'm trying to do this thing in Ubuntu because i need to run this program with this command witch opens a debug option. but i can't find a solution for it if there is any.

i tried to browsing files through wine and open the file properties that way but nothing happens when i try to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me. [In play on linux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/) 
If you open configure there is a field for arguments where i entered my argument and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal window, and enter the command

`wine /path/to/executable/program.exe [option] [option]`

You can use this to start your program with a debug option.

Comment: Ok it tried this the game opens but the debug mode does not

i tried bot "\nwcgrail", "-nwcgrail" and "--nwcgrail"

Comment: I think that in Linux, you will need to escape the '/' character:  try `\/nwcgrail`

Comment: i fond my problem i misstyped / as \

Comment: still did not get it to work i did find the sulotion in play on linux